# Retrieve data from dynamically created EditBox in android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have created dynamic EditText boxes and spinner on Add button, but I don't know how to retrieve data from them. [The whole code is available on this website.](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/dynamically-add-and-remove-views-in-android/)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);
            mText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);


        }
        public void onAddField(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);

            // Add the new row before the add field button.
            parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
            parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(counter);
        }

        public void onDelete(View v) {
            parentLinearLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You can simply create loop and get all data which have added dynamically, like this :

Change your layout activity_main.xml because in demo they were doing wrong code for layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/number_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:inputType="phone"/>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/type_spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:entries="@array/types"
            android:gravity="right" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:onClick="onDelete"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_field_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#555"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onAddField"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:text="Add Field"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/result"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code for getting all values of edit Text :

```
 int count = parentLinearLayout.getChildCount();

 for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
     LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
     EditText editText = (EditText)linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
     String result = editText.getText().toString();
     //You can result get data from edit text.
 }
```

For Spinner Value :

```
int count = parentLinearLayout.getChildCount();

     for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
         LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
         Spinner spinnerField = (Spinner)linearLayout.getChildAt(1);
         String result = spinnerField.getSelectedItem().toString();
         //You can result get data from spinner value.
     }
```

Comment: v.getText() is throwing error called cannot resolve method

Comment: getText method is not supported by v object

Comment: Can you show me R.layout.field xml , because edit text must be next direct child of parentlayout and also have you parsed view in Edit Text ?

Comment: I used this exact same code https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/dynamically-add-and-remove-views-in-android/

Comment: ohkay wait a movement i will give you exact code and you just need to place , get the result.

Comment: Sir your logic worked for EditText boxes but when I use the same logic to retrieve data from spinner it is throwing android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner exception

Comment: Means you have added spinner place of edit text right ?

Comment: It was already present in the code,I just did not try to retrieve data from it before

Comment: Please check my edited code . I have also mentioned for spinner value code.

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me out so much

Answer (score 0):

```
   mText=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);
```

Put this in onAddField method.

When you want to get the text from the ediText you need to call

```
mText.getText().toString()
```